# PySpark DateTime Functions returning nulls

Tags: pyspark

I am reading in some Chicago Crimes data, and needs to use the built in pyspark datetime functions to create a month and year column. I have followed the documentation and tried several methods with no luck.

I import the following.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, from_unixtime
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
```

My schema shows the Date, and it has string values.

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Case_Number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Block: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IUCR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Primary_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Location_Description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Arrest: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- Domestic: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- District: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Community_Area: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FBI_Code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- X_Coordinate: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Y_Coordinate: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Updated_On: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Location: string (nullable = true)
```

See values, there are no nulls in the data column.

```
df.select('Date').show()
+--------------+
|          Date|
+--------------+
|9/5/2015 13:30|
|9/4/2015 11:30|
| 9/1/2018 0:01|
|9/5/2015 12:45|
|9/5/2015 13:00|
|9/5/2015 10:55|
|9/4/2015 18:00|
|9/5/2015 13:00|
|9/5/2015 11:30|
| 5/1/2016 0:25|
|9/5/2015 14:00|
|9/5/2015 11:00|
| 9/5/2015 3:00|
|9/5/2015 12:50|
|9/3/2015 13:00|
|9/5/2015 11:45|
|9/5/2015 13:30|
| 7/8/2015 0:00|
| 9/5/2015 9:55|
|9/5/2015 12:35|
+--------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Then I call the following but get all nulls.

```
 df2 = df.withColumn("Date", unix_timestamp("Date", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"))
    df2.select("Date").show()
    +----------+
    |      Date|
    +----------+
    |      null|
    |1441384200|
    |      null|
    |1441431900|
    |      null|
    |1441468500|
    |      null|
    |      null|
    |1441470600|
    |      null|
    |      null|
    |1441468800|
    |1441440000|
    |1441432200|
    |      null|
    |1441471500|
    |      null|
    |      null|
    |1441464900|
    |1441431300|
    +----------+
    only showing top 20 rows

df2 = df.withColumn("Date", df.Date.cast(types.TimestampType()))
df2.select("Date").show()
+----+
|Date|
+----+
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
|null|
+----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I want to just use the Date column to create Month and Year.

```
### Get Month from date in pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import month, year
#df = df.withColumn("Date", df.Date.cast(types.TimestampType()))
#df = df.withColumn("Date", unix_timestamp("Date", "MM/dd/yyyy"))
df = df.withColumn('Year', year(df['Date']))
df = df.withColumn('Month', month(df['Date']))

In: df.select('Month').distinct().collect()
Out: [Row(Month=None)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok first of all - some reproducable example would have been nice..

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('stack').getOrCreate()
data = [("9/5/2015 13:30"),("9/4/2015 11:30"), ("9/1/2018 0:01"), ("9/5/2015 12:45"),("9/5/2015 13:00"), ("9/5/2015 10:55"), ("9/4/2015 18:00"), ("9/5/2015 13:00")]
from pyspark.sql.types import *

dummy_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, StringType()).toDF('Datetime')
dummy_df.show()
dummy_df.printSchema()
```

that will give you the output:

```
+--------------+
|      Datetime|
+--------------+
|9/5/2015 13:30|
|9/4/2015 11:30|
| 9/1/2018 0:01|
|9/5/2015 12:45|
|9/5/2015 13:00|
|9/5/2015 10:55|
|9/4/2015 18:00|
|9/5/2015 13:00|
+--------------+
root
 |-- Datetime: string (nullable = true)
```

Now, as mentioned before be carefull with the format of the date-column and follow the instructions of https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, month, year, col, to_date

#simple regex, watch out for the white space
dummy_df = dummy_df.withColumn('Date', regexp_replace('Datetime', '( \d+:\d+)', ''))
#transform the date-column
dummy_df = dummy_df.withColumn('Date', to_date(col('Date'), "M/d/y"))\ 
        .withColumn('Month', month(col('Date')))\
        .withColumn('Year', year(col('Date')))
dummy_df.show()
dummy_df.printSchema()
```

finally we get:

```
+--------------+----------+-----+----+
|      Datetime|      Date|Month|Year|
+--------------+----------+-----+----+
|9/5/2015 13:30|2015-09-05|    9|2015|
|9/4/2015 11:30|2015-09-04|    9|2015|
| 9/1/2018 0:01|2018-09-01|    9|2018|
|9/5/2015 12:45|2015-09-05|    9|2015|
|9/5/2015 13:00|2015-09-05|    9|2015|
|9/5/2015 10:55|2015-09-05|    9|2015|
|9/4/2015 18:00|2015-09-04|    9|2015|
|9/5/2015 13:00|2015-09-05|    9|2015|
+--------------+----------+-----+----+

root
 |-- Datetime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- Month: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Year: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use the timestampFormat option when reading data in pyspark. I combine it with schema injection when reading csv files:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *


def main():

    print('Spark read Crimes DataFrames inject schema')

    # Create Spark Session
    spark: SparkSession = (SparkSession
                           .builder
                           #.config("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
                           .appName('Spark Course')
                           .getOrCreate())

    # Define schema of the data
    schema: StructType = StructType([
        StructField('ID', IntegerType(), nullable=False),
        StructField('Case_Number', StringType(), nullable=False),
        StructField('Date', TimestampType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Block', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('IUCR', StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Primary_Type', StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Description', StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Location_Description', StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Arrest', BooleanType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Domestic', BooleanType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('District', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Community_Area', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('FBI_Code', StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('X_Coordinate', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Y_Coordinate', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Year', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Updated_On', StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField('Location', StringType(), nullable=True)
    ])

    # Read csv injecting schema
    crimes: DataFrame = (spark
                         .read
                         #.option('timestampFormat', "MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss a")  # Use with "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
                         .option('timestampFormat', "M/d/y h:m:s a")
                         .csv('/home/san/Downloads/Crimes_-_2001_to_Present.csv.crdownload', header=True, schema=schema))
    crimes.show()
    crimes.printSchema()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to execute process: {}'.format(e))
```

You can store this code in crimes.py and run it with

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit crimes.py
```

Please, pay attention to the new date an timestamp format instroduced in Spark 3: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

You can always use old format configuring spark session with
`.config("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")`